# Merge git head onto previous branch

Tags: git

[image]

I have a git history that looks like this. Is it possible (and how would I) to merge the changes made in commit 5 (in unrelated files than commits 3 and 4) onto commit 2?

Comment: Create a new branch at Commit 2 and then Cherry-Pick Commit 5 onto that branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Create a branch off of Commit 2
2. Cherry-pick Commit 5 into that new branch

If the hash for Commit 2 is a84212677 and the hash for Commit 5 is 2677a8421, then you'd do the following:

```
> git co a84212677
> git co -b newbranch
> git cherry-pick 2677a8421
```

Your Git repo would then look like this:

[image]